# My sound is not working

Tags: sound

I am not able to hear any sound. Does anyone have a clue how to proceed in fixing this?

Issuing `aplay` gives this

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 1: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: please check with alsamixer or pavucontrol if you volume is not set to zero by accident, happens all the time to me

Answer (score 2):

Start with [Ubuntu SoundTroubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)